# create table with @ManyToMany and @ManyToOne relation

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb

I'm struggling with creating tables with @ManyToMany and @ManyToOne relations.

I have to create 3 tables, person, country, gender.
Person and country relationship @ManyToMany and person, gender @ManyToOne.

Is my code correct?

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `di_person` (
        `id_person` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        `name` VARCHAR(256) ,
        `last_name` VARCHAR(256) ,
         `additional_info` VARCHAR(256) ,
        `gender_id` VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE REFERENCES di_gender,
        `country_id` VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE REFERENCES di_country
    ) COLLATE='utf8_bin';

-- ----------------------------------------------------- 
-- Table 'gender` 
-- ----------------------------------------------------- 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `di_gender` (
         id_gender INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    id_person INT,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    CONSTRAINT tb_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_person) REFERENCES di_person(id_person)
    ) COLLATE='utf8_bin';

-- ----------------------------------------------------- 
-- Table 'country` 
-- ----------------------------------------------------- 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `di_country` (
        `id_country` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        `name`  VARCHAR(256), 
        `id_person` VARCHAR (10) UNIQUE REFERENCES di_person
    ) COLLATE='utf8_bin';
```

Comment: Try to use one table (person), where `gender` and `country` just text fields.

Comment: you mean just change to: `gender_id VARCHAR (50) and country _id VARCHAR (50)`without references?

Comment: Yes. (Who created 15 symbols restriction  for comment???)

Answer (score 0):

I would have said not. Person is unique and should only have one entry per person. I suggest that the gender should remain in person and have a foreign key reference for validation purposes (i don't like enums), but am a bit dubious about holding country in the person table (more of this later). Gender should not have the person id and neither should country -otherwise duplicates of gender and country would exist. Not knowing what your data looks like i might create a person_country junction table so that a person can be associated with more than one country if that will never be the case then holding the country code in person (with a foreign key constraint) would be fine.